# How can I stop my program from generating the same key?

Tags: python, passwords, generator

I writing a password generator and I ran into this annoying issue, and it is the repeating a a number or letter on the same line. The user gives the program a format on how they want their password to be generated ex "C@@d%%%"
where @ is only letters and where % is only numbers, and the user also inputs the numbers and letters to generate the password, then the program is suppose to print out something like cold123, but instead it prints out cood111 or clld111, I will post a snippet of my code below, but please don't bad mouth it, I'm fairly new to python, self-taught and just about couple of months into the python experience.

```
class G()
    .
    .
    .

    # self.forms is the format the user input they can input things such as C@@d%%% 
    # where @ is only letters and where % is only numbers

    # self.Bank is a list where generated things go 

    AlphaB = [] #list Of All Of The Positions That have The @ sign in The self.forms 
    NumB = [] #list of All of the positions that have a % sign
    for char in self.forms: 
        if char == '@':
            EOL=(self.Position) # Positions End Of Line
            Loc = self.forms[EOL] # Letter
            AlphaB.append(EOL)  


        if char == '%':
            EOL=(self.Position)
            Loc = self.forms[EOL]
            NumB.append(EOL)
        self.Position+=1 # Move right a position

    for pos in AlphaB: 
        for letter in self.alphas: #letters in The User Inputs
            GenPass=(self.forms.replace(self.forms[pos],letter))
            #Not Fully Formatted yet, because Only The letter been formatted
            if GenPass.find('%'):
                for Pos in NumB:
                    for number in self.ints:
                        GenPass=(GenPass.replace(GenPass[Pos],number))
                        if GenPass not in self.Bank:
                            #Cood111
                            print (GenPass)
                            self.Bank.append(GenPass)

            else:
                if GenPass not in self.Bank:
                    print (GenPass)
                    self.Bank.append(GenPass)
```

Comment: This is an exercise, right? Not going into production code?

Comment: I think the problem is the `replace()` function which replaces all occurrences of old with the new. I believe if you pass it a third argument `,1` then only the first occurrence will be replaced instead of all of them

Answer (score 0):

`GenPass.replace(GenPass[Pos],number)` will replace *every* occurrence of the character at `GenPass[Pos]` with the value of `number`. You need to make sure you replace one character at a time.

Comment: to replace one at a time you could simply add a third argument to `replace` to something like `GenPass.replace(GenPass[Pos],number,1)` and only the first will be replaced

Comment: how? the replace thing replace everything

Comment: so basically  GenPass.replace(GenPass[Pos],number,int(Pos))

Comment: the replace statement only modify the first in text, but ignoring the others

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all chars and a list with all nums, then just pick one by using list.pop(randint(0, len(list) - 1), you will always pick a different letter / number like this but you will also be limited to 10 digits (0-9) and 20-something letters.

Comment: Popping from the list is a terrible idea - you're reducing the entropy of the password right off the bat.

Comment: Is it possible to not repeat characters without reducing entropy?